# angular 2 + firebase app gets user logged out on refresh

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-services

Im new to all that means Angular2, Firebase, SPAs, etc. These days I have a task to add some new functionality to an Angular2 (with Firebase email&pw auth) app. The app consists mainly of a blog(the main page), a shop(/shop) and admin area(/admin) form which you can manage both blog posts and shop items. One of a requirements of the task is to make the app to maintain the session if you hit refresh on the browser, so that if you are on any "page" from /admin area, you wont be brought back to login form, which currently happens. I literally spent hours on the web looking for a solution and I failed to find one. I tried to save a localstorage token but found that firebase already does that, and many other things, but still couldnt find a solution. App already have a mechanism to check for logged in user, and a route guard, used on the manage blog (/admin/bog-admin) and manage products(/admin/product-admin) sections in the admin area. I will try to post what I think is relevant for this problem, feel free to ask for more code snippets if I forgot anything. Also please explain briefly your solution since I really need to understand it too.
**user.service.ts :**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  Router,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';


@Injectable()
export class UserService implements CanActivate {
  userLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  loggedInUser: string;
  authUser: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, public toastr: ToastsManager) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "AIzaSyB7VgN55gflpKAlmM41r2DCdUsy69JkLsk",
      authDomain: "angulargigabyte-966ef.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://angulargigabyte-966ef.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "angulargigabyte-966ef",
      storageBucket: "angulargigabyte-966ef.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "154241614671"
    })
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.verifyLogin(url);
  }

  verifyLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.userLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/admin/login']);
    return false;
  }

  register(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert(`${error.message} Please Try Again!`);
      });
  }

  verifyUser() {
    this.authUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (this.authUser) {

      this.toastr.success('Alert', `Welcome ${this.authUser.email}`);
      this.loggedInUser = this.authUser.email;
      this.userLoggedIn = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
    }
  }

  login(loginEmail: string, loginPassword: string) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail, loginPassword)
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert(`${error.message} Unable to login. Try again!`);
      });
  }

  logout() {
    this.userLoggedIn = false;
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {

    }, function (error) {
      alert(`${error.message} Unable to logout. Try again!`);
    });
  }

}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../adminShared/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
 })

export class LoginComponent { 
  email: string;
  password1: string;

  constructor(private userSVC: UserService, private router: Router){}

  login(){
    this.userSVC.login(this.email, this.password1);
    this.userSVC.verifyUser();
  }

  signup(){
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/signup']);
  }

  cancel(){
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use angularfire2? (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

You could use the Observable authState, like:

```
afAuth.authState.subscribe((resp) => {
  if (resp.uid){
    //user is already logged
  }
});
```

More info in https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md

Comment: thanks for answering. im afraid i might not be allowed to use other frameworks than those i already have in the app.